# Copies of or a copy of?

Tags: grammatical-number

Would you say, "I sent him copies of the motion and the letter," or would you say, "I sent him a copy of the motion and the letter"?

Comment: Depends on how many you sent him...

Comment: @Heartspring I think the issue is that he sent 1 copy each of 2 documents. So is it singular or plural?

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the motion and letter to be one combined document, then it's singular "copy".

If they're two separate documents, then there are two copies -- one copy of the motion, and one copy of the letter.